# Can stripped metal on a power button ribbon be repaired?

Tags: laptop, power, ribbon

I was struggling with a power button cable going into the motherboard (the clip was broken), and in the meantime I managed to strip the ribbon going into the motherboard.

I reversed the cable and used a pair of tweezers to jump start the laptop as a temporary measure.

Can I salvage this cable? I was thinking about cutting off the end of the ribbon flush since it's only stripped on the end.

Here's a video of the stripped cable and how I jumpstarted it:

[Video of stripped cable and jumpstarting](https://youtu.be/wLpopqBk8y4)

Comment: It's hard to tell exactly what's stripped from your description and the video, and whatever you do with the tweezers is off camera.  Is it the cable or the connector that's damaged?  Is what's missing insulation or metal contacts?  Have you explored replacing the connector if that's the damaged part?

Comment: Pause at 0:12. All I did off camera was apply the tweezers to the surface of the ribbon (metal parts)

Comment: Auto parts stores sell rear window defroster repair in a bottle, it is copper infused glue, you could use this to make new metal traces, probabaly not an easy task as the traces need to be separate.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u_v942ySQHA

Comment: That is a really interesting idea.

Answer (score 1):

I've done this before by accident. If you've simply bent the exposed metal contacts away from the cable, super glue them back down and then very gently scrape any glue residue (after it dries) off the exposed contact sides. Do this very, very lightly and only as much as is required to make contact. In fact once you get the leads glued back down, it might be wiser to simply use a very small amount of acetone (like, a single drop) on a cotton swab to clean any glue residue from the exposed contacts, rather than scraping. They are very delicate, and will break and or peel off the ribbon very easily.

If trimming the cable is necessary, you're going to have issues as you try to trim plastic off to expose new contact points, as the metal is going to peel from the backing very easily, and you'll find yourself trimming and trying again, only to have the foil peel again, and next thing you know your cable is now too short and you've wasted a lot of time. In the event that you need to trim the cable, I'm not sure that there is a viable solution, except possibly to try to trim to expose new leads using a razor.

Obviously your best bet is to just buy a new cable. If you try to use a chemical aid at all like acetone, be advised that it will chew through plastics (as it will the glue residue) and these cables are obviously made from similar compounds, so be very careful. Also, obviously take into consideration all of the safety requirements of handling hazardous chemicals (ventilation, contact etc).

Comment: I didn't bend them back, they were scraped off.

Although I wonder if instead of cutting the scrapped part off, if I could bend it back to expose the metal to the power board?

Comment: If you've got a lip where the one side of the plastic ribbon starts, hook a razor onto that plastic lip and just trim back the plastic, then cut the ribbon straight across